# postgres dblink_connect ERROR: could not establish connection

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to connect to another server using pgadmin3. This is what I am doing:

```
CREATE EXTENSION dblink;

select postal.* from dblink('host=<name>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com
 user=postgres
 password=postgres
 dbname=name', 'select * from xwg201703.gc_bgr_postcodes')
 AS postal(country varchar(3), 
    postalcode  varchar(4),
    town_bul varchar(60),
    town_bun varchar(60),
    locality_bul varchar(60),
    locality_bun varchar(60))
limit 1;
```

The error I get:
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host ".amazonaws.com" (...) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

Any input would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use postgres as username on RDS

before creating dblink, check if you can connect at all. eg:

```
psql -h host=<name>.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com -U username -d db_name
```

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have different username and password here. 'postgres' was a place holder. I am able to connect to that particular database. But my goal is to connect from one database into another (I am using pgadmin3 for my SQL )